# confused about calling `self` in a finder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `Vote`, and I'm using an `after_validation` callback.

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_validation :destroy_reciprocal_votes

  belongs_to :voteable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :voter, :polymorphic => true

  private

  def destroy_reciprocal_votes
    votes = Vote.delete_all(:vote => false, :voteable_type => "Recipe", :voteable_id => self.voteable_id, :voter_type => "User", :voter_id => self.voter_id)
  end
end
```

You can see that in my method `destroy_reciprocal_votes`, I called `self.voteable_id` and `self.voter_id`, why does this return `nil`? and how should I retrieve my id's here?

*When I do it in console it works fine:*

```
>> voteable_id = "3"
>> voter_id = "162"
>> Vote.delete_all(:vote => false, :voteable_type => "Recipe", :voteable_id => voteable_id, :voter_type => "User", :voter_id => voter_id)
```

Comment: is the `private` preventing me from calling `self` on an instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to refer to **id** as long as you specify an association. Try this:

```
Vote.delete_all(:vote => false, :voteable_type => "Recipe", :voteable_id => voteable, :voter_type => "User", :voter_id => voter)
```

**Update**

Changed to **:voteable_id => voteable**.

Comment: well, It seems I do since that is a the column in the db and it's polymorphic. If I should be able to do so let me know, because that would be a bit cleaner.

Comment: A short example:>> Post.find(:all, :conditions=>{ :user_id => User.find(:first) } )

Comment: Well because it is truly a polymorphic model, like the user can cast votes on `features` and they can cast votes on `recipes` so I need to make sure that I'm deleting the proper vote.

Comment: [answered above] Why do you need :voter_type, if you have :voter_id already? @Joseph, can you set up a testing environment and play with this example: Post.delete_all( :user_id => User.find(:first) ) - in application to your case? Should be working fine.

Comment: ha, I guess you were right, I did need to call self on it `:voteable_id => self.voteable` but now it is clean and simple.